# Is Classical Latin “proelium” (battle) in any way related to English “broil” (quarrel)?

Tags: classical-latin, etymology

I’m starting a Classical Latin course and I noticed that *proelium*, meaning *battle*, sounds very much like English *broil*/*embroil*, and could plausibly have some etymological relationship.

Is it just a coincidence, or am I onto something here?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be: https://www.etymonline.com/word/broil#etymonline_v_17148

Comment: @cmw It draws a comparison to Italian *imbroglio*. Is it possible that *proelium* derives from the same PIE root, namely *bhreu-*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We don't know, but it's unlikely!

Both of these words have uncertain etymologies. But there are reasons to think that the resemblances in form between *broil* and *proelium* are coincidental, which would mean they're no more likely to be related than any other pair of words of uncertain origin.

*Proelium* looks like it probably starts with the prefix *prō-/pro-.* This comes from a Proto-Indo-European source starting with *p, which regularly turns into Latin /p/ and Germanic *f (as in *from, for, first*).

There isn't an easy way for the start of *broil* to come from that same source.  The word *(em)broil* in the sense "struggle" seems to be from French *brouiller,* of uncertain origin, but often thought to be taken from a Germanic language. If *broil* is ultimately from a Germanic word, then the *b* would come from a PIE source starting in *bʰ. And PIE *bʰ at the start of a word regularly turned into Latin *f-*.* (If *broil* somehow had a Celtic source, which apparently has sometimes been proposed, we would also expect the initial /b/ to go back to *bʰ.)

As for the end of the words, according to one hypothesis the /l/ in French *brouiller* comes from a suffix rather than from the original root of the word (the hypothesis is Proto-Indo-European **bʰrewh₁-* > **brod-* in a West Germanic language > **brodicare* in Late Latin/Romance > **brodiculare* > French *brouiller*; see [CNRTL](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/brouiller) and [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/brouiller#French)).

---

*Some examples of words thought to come from **bʰrewh₁-* in Latin: *ferveo* "burn, boil, seethe", *fermentum* "fermentation, yeast", *dēfrutum* "boiled-down grape juice/must".